# Firebase EqualTo only returns one record - should return multiple

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Referring to the Firebase docs and example located here https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query

Their docs say it should return all dinosaurs who's height is 25. It only returns one.

```
// Find all dinosaurs whose height is exactly 25 meters.
var ref = firebase.database().ref("dinosaurs");
ref.orderByChild("height").equalTo(25).on("child_added", function(snapshot) 
{
  console.log(snapshot.key);
});
```

My Data looks like:

```
dinosaur
   - stega 
       height : 25
   - bronto 
       height : 25
```

Can someone clarify why I'm only getting one record back if the docs say it should return all?

Comment: Please recheck you data, your query is correct and it will return 2 records if everything else is fine

Comment: Hi, Spinteractive. I have checked it, works fine for me. See my jsfiddle sample https://jsfiddle.net/onohn08y/5/

Comment: Yours does. Thanks for checking. Mine does not. Here's a link to my data http://spinteractive.net/images/test.jpg - can you take a look?

Comment: The key for bronto height has a space at the end.

Comment: Thanks, Bob. I've been trying to figure that out all day. :) I can sleep well now. Always the simple little things that get you.